Is there any way to configure different timeouts for different users screen locking in Windows 11?
For example, there are 3 users:

Simple user
Advanced user
Admin user

Is there any options (3rd party software also can be used) to have for Simple user no timeout - it should not have any autolocking screen and Advanced with Admin should have something like 10 minutes timeout of inactivity?

One way to do this is with the screen saver settings:

Screen saver: None (optional)
Wait: 10 minutes
Enable "On resume, display logon screen"

They can be configured differently for each user

In a workplace-style environment, this can be enforced with user group policies, and only applied to specific users/groups:
User policies/Administrative Templates/Control Panel/Personalization/

Screen saver timeout
Password protect the screen saver

